# How to solve this recurrence equation with Mathematica?

Tags: difference-equations

[image]I am interested in solving this recurrence relation (equation) with Mathematica code. I am new to Mathematica. I tried RSolve, RSolveValue, AsymptoticRSolveValue commands for this. But I am not getting any result for different values of 'theta'. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == \[Theta]*a[n] (-1 + a[n]), a[0] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

Comment: A nonlinear recurrence is not likely to have an explicit solution known to *Mathematica*. Of course, you can still use `RecurrenceTable[]` or the method in Akku's solution to generate the terms.

Comment: Asymptotic solutions are `a[n] = 0` and `a[n] = 4/3`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a recursion relation (with memorizing former values, which speeds up) like

```
a[0] = a0; 
a[n_] := a[n] = \[Theta]*a[n - 1] (-1 + a[n - 1])

a[3]

(*   (-1 + a0) a0 \[Theta]^3 (-1 + (-1 + a0) a0 \[Theta]) (-1 + (-1 + 
  a0) a0 \[Theta]^2 (-1 + (-1 + a0) a0 \[Theta]))   *)
```

But with a[0]=1, you get zero for n>0.

Comment: Thank you very much.